REST API query doesn't understand custom relationship while it worked with CLI
We're trying to query our Salesforce data from another process. A colleague did a PoC with his own credentials on the CLI and got results. The query he created contains custom relations and that worked fine. Now we're trying to make this proper by using a connected app and doing the query via the REST API, but I get the infamous error message "didn't understand relationship".
The query is executed from some custom code. It first gets a JWT and then calls the /query endpoint. If I don't include relationships in my query I get results as expected, so I'm confident the surrounding code is not the problem.
The most simple query is this:
Select Name, abc__Account__r.Name from abc__Proj__c

The result is this error which seems quite common

Didn't understand relationship 'abc__Account__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

If I use the describe endpoint I don't see anything that helps me, I also don't really know what I'm looking for. There is no obvious list of relationships.
What should I be looking into to solve this? Would it be related to permissions? Is this supposed to work in the REST API? Unfortunately our Salesforce admin doesn't know anything about to integrate with other systems.

Is it perhaps an permission issue? Can you run this query from the dev console? Which user are you using as the subject for the JWT (and do they have permission to read the Account relationship field/the Account)? Any possibility that there's something like territories set up that would restrict Account visibility?

Role Hierarchies could be another thing restricting record visibility.

Despite our administrator saying that there was nothing wrong with the permissions, there was something wrong with the permissions. Thank you for thinking along.
